# assign value dervied from an id groupby to each id of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

The problem is the following:

In words:

For each ids in the dataframe, from all the dates in variable "date1" smaller to the dates in variable "date2", get the highest one, once you have that highest date, use it to find the values of "var1" and "var2" and divde those two to get a new variable "var3", extrapolate that variable to fill all the rows for each id with that value that you get (each value will be different for each id).

Visually:
This is the dataset "df":

```
    ID    date1      date2    var1   var2
0   1   2017-11-29  2017-12-12  50  60
1   1   2017-12-04  2017-12-12  57  34
2   1   2017-12-15  2017-12-12  43  55
3   1   2018-01-12  2017-12-12  11  75
4   2   2019-03-11  2019-03-27  33  73
5   2   2019-03-25  2019-03-27  22  71
6   2   2019-03-28  2019-03-27  54  70
7   2   2019-05-21  2019-03-27  35  55
8   3   2017-09-05  2017-09-23  67  78
9   3   2017-09-22  2017-09-23  72  71
```

So, basically

for example for ID 1: when "date1" < "date2", give the max date (which would be 2017-12-04), in the row where that date is grab the values of "var1" and "var2" (57 and 34) and divide them to create "var3" (equal 1.67), then extrapolate that value to fill all the rows for id 1, like this:

```
    ID    date1      date2    var1  var2 var3
0   1   2017-11-29  2017-12-12  50  60   1.67
1   1   2017-12-04  2017-12-12  57  34   1.67
2   1   2017-12-15  2017-12-12  43  55   1.67
3   1   2018-01-12  2017-12-12  11  75   1.67
```

The idea is not to get a groupby dataframe, but the original dataframe.

My attempt:

```
max_date = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['date1']<x['date2'],'date1'].max()))
max_date.name = "max_date"
df = pd.merge(df,max_date,"left",left_on="id",right_index=True)
var3_var1 = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['date1']==x['date2'],"var1"])
var3_var2 = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['date1']==x['date2'],"var2"])
var3 = var3_var1/var3_var2
var3.name = "var3"
df = pd.merge(df,var3,"left",left_on="id",right_index=True)
```

The code is not fully working, but it is getting close, my main problem is using `merge` since I will lose the `id` columns, I know I can simply re-attach the index, but overall with the code above doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: ID2 and 3 don't have any date1 < date2

Comment: Yeah sorry, this one is just an extract of many more rows, I will change that to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer to this question is great.  This approach is similar to what I think you were trying to do, hopefully it helps shed some light on other ways to solve the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
 'date1': ['2017-11-29',
  '2017-12-04',
  '2017-12-15',
  '2018-01-12',
  '2019-03-11',
  '2019-03-25',
  '2019-03-28',
  '2019-05-21',
  '2017-09-05',
  '2017-09-22'],
 'date2': ['2017-12-12',
  '2017-12-12',
  '2017-12-12',
  '2017-12-12',
  '2019-03-27',
  '2019-03-27',
  '2019-03-27',
  '2019-03-27',
  '2017-09-23',
  '2017-09-23'],
 'var1': [50, 57, 43, 11, 33, 22, 54, 35, 67, 72],
 'var2': [60, 34, 55, 75, 73, 71, 70, 55, 78, 71]})

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

# Sorting allows us to use groupby/first in the next line which simplifies things a lot
df.sort_values(by='date1', ascending=False, inplace=True)

m = df.loc[df['date1']<df['date2']].groupby('ID').first().apply(lambda x: x['var1']/x['var2'],
                                                                axis=1).reset_index(name='var3')

df = df.merge(m, on='ID').sort_values(by=['ID','date1','date2'])
```

Output

```
   ID      date1      date2  var1  var2      var3
7   1 2017-11-29 2017-12-12    50    60  1.676471
6   1 2017-12-04 2017-12-12    57    34  1.676471
5   1 2017-12-15 2017-12-12    43    55  1.676471
4   1 2018-01-12 2017-12-12    11    75  1.676471
3   2 2019-03-11 2019-03-27    33    73  0.309859
2   2 2019-03-25 2019-03-27    22    71  0.309859
1   2 2019-03-28 2019-03-27    54    70  0.309859
0   2 2019-05-21 2019-03-27    35    55  0.309859
9   3 2017-09-05 2017-09-23    67    78  1.014085
8   3 2017-09-22 2017-09-23    72    71  1.014085
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
def f(d):
    d_ = d.query('date1 < date2')
    if not d_.empty:
        i = d_.date1.idxmax()
        return d.assign(var3=d.at[i, 'var1'] / d.at[i, 'var2'])

df.groupby('ID', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(f)

   ID      date1      date2  var1  var2      var3
0   1 2017-11-29 2017-12-12    50    60  1.676471
1   1 2017-12-04 2017-12-12    57    34  1.676471
2   1 2017-12-15 2017-12-12    43    55  1.676471
3   1 2018-01-12 2017-12-12    11    75  1.676471
```